# django - use chunk to read uploaded file will break down some row

Tags: python, django, csv, file-upload, chunks

I want to use `for chunk in f.chunks()` to read a huge csv file. It works well in first record, but I found it will break the row when the rows reach chunk's size  As I know the chunk's default size is 64KB. For example, I have three rows in csv file:

- 'this is first row'
- 'this is second row'
- 'this is third row'

when I use `for chunk in f.chunks()`, I expect to get

> chunk1 contains 'this is first row', chunk2 contains ('this is second row', 'this is third row' ) 
>   or
>   chunk1 contains ('this is first row','this is second row'), chunk2 contains ( 'this is third row' )

but the real result will be:

> chunk1 contains ('this is first row', 'this is'), chunk2 contains ('second row', 'this is third row')

That it is, it will break second row 'this is second row' into different chunks. Is it possible to prevent chunk breaking the row?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and discovered that when you iterate over lines in a Django `File` object, Django reads the file in chunks, and has logic to "repair" lines that may be broken up by chunk boundaries! Specifically, take a look at the [File.__iter__()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/core/files/base/#File.__iter__) method:

```
def __iter__(self):
    # Iterate over this file-like object by newlines
    buffer_ = None
    for chunk in self.chunks():
        for line in chunk.splitlines(True):
            if buffer_:
                if endswith_cr(buffer_) and not equals_lf(line):
                    # Line split after a \r newline; yield buffer_.
                    yield buffer_
                    # Continue with line.
                else:
                    # Line either split without a newline (line
                    # continues after buffer_) or with \r\n
                    # newline (line == b'\n').
                    line = buffer_ + line
                # buffer_ handled, clear it.
                buffer_ = None

            # If this is the end of a \n or \r\n line, yield.
            if endswith_lf(line):
                yield line
            else:
                buffer_ = line

    if buffer_ is not None:
        yield buffer_
```

Given this, as long as `f` is a Django `File` object, you can simply do:

```
for line in f:
    # Do your stuff here
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think is not that simple. Django manages uploaded files like binary files. Instead of working with fixed length chunks I recommend use your f.file object, and iterate using readline method.

```
my_file = f.file
while True:
    line = my_file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    # Do your stuff
```

Not quite elegant, but useful